# Is Ethereum blockchain public?

Tags: blockchain, contract-design, privacy

I have some idea of a smart contract, that based on private user tokens which stored in contract state. Every user can set his token by sending transaction to contract. But it is not secure if every user on network has access to all transactions data.

Is there way to store private user data in contract store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire Blockchain is public and distributed among nodes.

The only way to store data which you want to be private on the Blockchain would be encryption.